# How to identify a network connectivity exception in Java?

Tags: java, networking, exception

I would like to uniquely identify network connectivity exceptions so I can warn the user there was a recoverable connectivity problem.

Many methods in Java throw `IOException` but it is difficult to know if the particular IOException is something that is caused by connectivity problems that could be resolved by the user establishing a proper/better network connection versus an issue that the user would have no way of recovering from such as an IOException caused by local file read/write issues or programmer error.

I think there are generally a few standard connectivity exceptions but I'm not sure. I assume it may also be influenced by which network client is being used, Apache HTTP Client, OkHttp, network Sockets, etc. Is this a solvable problem, and if so which exceptions are connectivity exceptions?

Comment: Get the exact type of the thrown IOException subclass (..  HttpRetryException, IIOException, InterruptedByTimeoutException, InterruptedIOException..) and go from there?

Comment: For the list of common networking exceptions you can check this http://vaibhavblogs.org/2012/12/common-java-networking-exceptions/

Comment: For the list of Java network exceptions and their meanings ***read the Javadoc.*** There is no point in consulting possibly flawed or obsolete third party sources. @SergeiSirik

Comment: This is a very broad question.  Maybe you could outline a specific scenario?

Comment: @JohnnyV Connectivity exceptions happen frequently (poor cell coverage, stuck behind Wi-Fi paywall, ISP down), but other exceptions might be a sign of a more serious problem. Obviously things like `NullPointerException` are programmer error, but an `IOException` itself could be something like "file not found" or maybe a TLS certificate expired. If I can categorize the exceptions properly then for connectivity exceptions I can inform the user that they should check their network and maybe give them some tips (find better wi-fi etc), and other issues I can report back to my server.

Comment: @satur9nine right, but where in your code?  Obviously anything thrown during a connect/accept/read/write to the Socket or SocketChannel objects are connectivity/socket errors.  TLS, etc errors are all occurring elsewhere.  If you have a problem with a specific abstraction to sockets then you should ask the question about that.  For example, "how do I tell if an OkHttp IOException is a socket problem or something else" then provide all your code.